# How to save state of radio button in android

Tags: android, radio-button

I want to save the state of radio button clicked in android. When user goes to next question it must save state so when he comes back to previous state it must show the selected option.

Comment: Try using shared preferences.

Comment: shreya it means i have to make method to save and On Next button click and on Prev button click i must call that function..

Comment: I think there must be a simple method for this , 

See RadioGroup r = (RadioGroup)findviewbyid(R.layout.rgroup);

So r.clearCheck(); i used it clears the thing so on above this , can i put some so it can save like that.... 

I am just asking other wise will use shared prefernces

Comment: No. There is no any other method to save state as far as I know. You will have to do it manually

Answer (score 2):

Use Shared Preferences, To save your radio button's state,and you get to retrieve data in other activities.

this is java class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;

public class ABCD extends Activity{


    private int ival;
    public static int glob=1;
    static SharedPreferences sPref;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor sE;
    RadioGroup rbMain;
    RadioButton rb1,rb2,rb3,rb4,rb5;   

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);

        rbMain = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgMain);
        rb1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        rb2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        rb3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio3);
        rb4 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio4);
        rb5 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio5);

        sPref = getSharedPreferences("Pref",0);
        sE = sPref.edit();
        ival = sPref.getInt("Pref", 0);

        if(ival == R.id.radio1){
            rb1.setChecked(true);
            glob=1;
        }else if(ival == R.id.radio2){
            rb2.setChecked(true);   
            glob=2;
        }else if(ival == R.id.radio3){
            rb3.setChecked(true);
            glob=3;
        }else if(ival == R.id.radio4){
            rb4.setChecked(true);   
            glob=4;
        }else if(ival == R.id.radio5){
            rb5.setChecked(true);
            glob=5;
        }

        rbMain.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            int state = 0;
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                if(checkedId == R.id.radio1){
                    sE.clear();
                    sE.putInt("Pref", checkedId);
                    sE.apply();
                }else if(checkedId == R.id.radio2){
                    sE.clear();
                    sE.putInt("Pref", checkedId);
                    sE.apply();
                }else if(checkedId == R.id.radio3){
                    sE.clear();
                    sE.putInt("Pref", checkedId);
                    sE.apply();
                }else if(checkedId == R.id.radio4){
                    sE.clear();
                    sE.putInt("Pref", checkedId);
                    sE.apply();
                }else if(checkedId == R.id.radio5){
                    sE.clear();
                    sE.putInt("Pref", checkedId);
                    sE.apply();
                }

            }
        });

    }   

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
        sPref = getSharedPreferences("Pref",0);
        sE = sPref.edit();
        ival = sPref.getInt("Pref", 0);

        if(ival == R.id.radio1){
            rb1.setChecked(true);
            glob=1;
        }else if(ival == R.id.radio2){
            rb2.setChecked(true);   
            glob=2;
        }else if(ival == R.id.radio3){
            rb3.setChecked(true);
            glob=3;
        }else if(ival == R.id.radio4){
            rb4.setChecked(true);   
            glob=4;
        }else if(ival == R.id.radio5){
            rb5.setChecked(true);
            glob=5;
        }
    }

}
```

and this is my XML Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@color/white"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    >
 <RadioGroup android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/rgMain">
        <RadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radio1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true" android:text="1" android:textColor="@color/back">         
        </RadioButton>
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2" android:textColor="@color/back">            
        </RadioButton>
        <RadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radio3" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3" android:textColor="@color/back">            
        </RadioButton>
        <RadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radio4" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4" android:textColor="@color/back">            
        </RadioButton>
        <RadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radio5" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5" android:textColor="@color/back">            
        </RadioButton>
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

And, this can help you to do whatever you need.